# Global symmetry and particle multiplets

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, symmetry, standard-model

In chapter 20, of Peskin and Schroeder's quantum field theory book, they start with a comment that a global symmetry that is manifest lead to *particle multiplets* with *restricted interactions*. Can someone please explain how does a global symmetry does so with an example. I cannot understand this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example would be strong isospin, which is an approximate global symmetry of the Standard Model.

The isospin doublet in this case is
$$ \begin{pmatrix} p \\ n \end{pmatrix}.$$
But there also is an isospin triplett
$$ \begin{pmatrix} \pi^+ \\ \pi^0 \\ \pi^- \end{pmatrix}.$$

The symmetry restricts the ways in which these particles can decay. Since this is only an approximate symmetry, there are decays violating stron isospin, but their branching ratios are strongly supresed w.r.t. isospin conserving decays.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is the interpretation: every global (and continuos) symmetry of the lagrangian implies the existence of a conserved charge, using Noether's theorem. Charge commutes with the Hamiltonian, so there are some particle multiplets (same mass) labelled by the charge.
The simplest example is probably the global symmetry of a complex scalar field for a phase, that is $\phi \rightarrow e^{i \alpha} \phi$. In this case the associated charge can be seen as the electric charge of the field. 
Restricted interactions may be interpreted as the fact that under electromagnetic interactions only charged fields interact.

Similarly, a phase symmetry can give you conservation of barionic/leptonic number.

Comment: @ Rexcirus- I agree to you except at one point. I think in case of a global U(1) transformation that you have considered the corresponding conserved charge could be any U(1) charge, not necessarily the electric charge. Because to associate the conserved charge with electric charge we need to consider a local U(1) transformation (e.g., QED). Right? But I think they have something else in mind because they refer to interactions of particle multiplets. May be $SU(3)$ flavour symmetry. But how in that case the global symmetry restricts the interactions?

Comment: @SRS: The flavour symmetry is exactly alike the EM gauge $\mathrm{U}(1)$ in that it is a local/gauge symmetry. But the reasoning is nevertheless always the same as in this answer: Global (continuous) symmetries have conserved charges, and hence restrict the allowed interactions to the interactions that conserve this charge, whatever it may be.